# ASHX handler return 500 Internal server error

Tags: asp.net, web-services, ashx

I have the ASP.NET 4 asmx web service (IIS 7.5). It works by https. I added ashx handler. It works locally, but do not work at the hosting. Return 500 Internal Server Error. What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.Net will display a 500 if you don't have the `customErrors` property set to anything or it is set to `On`.

Add this to the web.config to see what the actual error is:

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

Once you know what the actual error is, you can proceed to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem when I changed the application pool in IIS from classic to integrated.  I solved it by adding a handler to the system.webServer of the web.config file.

```
<add verb="*" path="*.ashx" name="ImageFromDB"  type="ImageFromDB" />
```

like this:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add verb="*" path="*.ashx" name="ImageFromDB"  type="ImageFromDB" />
    </handlers>
 </system.webServer>
```

This added 'ImageFromDB' to the HandlerMappings in IIS.

This [link](https://assettrack.atlassian.net/wiki/display/IPD2/Ajax.NET+and+IIS+7+integrated+mode) was very helpful in pointing me in the right direction.